# PyQt5 как выполнить код вне окна с виджетами без его закрытия?

Tags: python, pyqt5

уважаемые колеги.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с PyQt5. Я начал осваивать его пару месяцев назад и не до конца понимаю как работает обработка потоков. В чём проблема: есть библиотека DevMeasMod, в которой имеем 2 класса: DataInput и Device. В классе DataInput создаётся окно для ввода пользователем данных. Я немного сократил исходный код для читаемости, т.к. содержание формы не имеет значения:

```
class DataInput(QWidget):


def __init__(self):

    super(DataInput, self).__init__()

    self.initUI()


def initUI(self):

    self.ex_event = False

    oImage = QImage('/.config/spyder/dna.jpg')
    sImage = oImage.scaled(QSize(600, 455))
    palette = QPalette()
    palette.setBrush(QPalette.Window, QBrush(sImage))
    self.setPalette(palette)

    self.header1 = QLabel(self)
    self.header1.setText(u'Информация об эксперименте: ')
    self.header1.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 14, 70))

    self.header2 = QLabel(self)
    self.header2.setText(u'Параметры процесса: ')
    self.header2.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 14, 70))

    self.empty = QLabel(self)
    self.empty.setText('')

    self.nameLabel = QLabel(self)
    self.nameLabel.setText(u'Эксперимент проводит: ')
    self.nameLabel.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 12, 60))
    self.nameLine = QLineEdit(self)

    openFile = QAction(QIcon('/.config/spyder   
/openicon.png'), 'Open', self)
    openFile.setStatusTip('Open file')
    openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)

    chbtn = QPushButton(self)
    chbtn.setIcon(QIcon('/.config/spyder/openicon.png'))
    chbtn.setIconSize(QSize(20, 15))
    chbtn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

    chbtns = QPushButton(self)
    chbtns.setIcon(QIcon('/.config/spyder/SaveIcon.png'))
    chbtns.setIconSize(QSize(20, 15))
    chbtns.clicked.connect(self.saveDialog)

    btn = QPushButton(u'Запуск', self)
    btn.setAutoDefault(True)
    btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: #7fc7ff")
    btn.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 12, 65))
    btn.clicked.connect(self.saving) 

    mainwindow = QVBoxLayout()
    self.setLayout(mainwindow)

    vertical1 = QHBoxLayout()
    vertical1.addWidget(self.header1)
    self.setLayout(vertical1)

    grid1 = QGridLayout()
    grid1.addWidget(self.nameLabel, 1, 0)
    grid1.addWidget(self.nameLine, 1, 1)
    grid1.addWidget(self.expnameLabel, 2, 0)
    grid1.addWidget(self.expnameLine, 2, 1)
    grid1.addWidget(self.expnumbLabel, 3, 0)
    grid1.addWidget(self.expnumbLine, 3, 1)
    grid1.addWidget(self.filenameLabel, 4, 0)
    grid1.addWidget(self.filenameLine, 4, 1)
    grid1.addWidget(self.savenameLabel, 5, 0)
    grid1.addWidget(self.savenameLine, 5, 1)
    grid1.addWidget(chbtn, 4, 2)
    grid1.addWidget(chbtns, 5, 2)

    hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    hbox.addStretch(1)
    hbox.addWidget(btn)
    hbox.addStretch(1)

    mainwindow.addLayout(vertical1) 
    mainwindow.addLayout(grid1)
    mainwindow.addStretch(1)
    mainwindow.addLayout(hbox)

    self.setLayout(hbox)
    self.setLayout(grid1)
    self.setToolTip(u'Пожалуйста введите информацию о проводимом 
эксперименте')
    self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    self.setFixedSize(600, 455)
    self.center()
    self.setWindowTitle(u'Ввод данных')
    self.show()        


def center(self):

    qr = self.frameGeometry()
    cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    self.move(qr.topLeft())


def showDialog(self):

    fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/home/gamma-
dna/.config/spyder')[0]
    self.filenameLine.setText(fname)


def saveDialog(self):

    put = os.getcwd()
    fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Save file', put)[0]
    self.savenameLine.setText(fname)


def saving(self):

    if (len(self.nameLine.text()) == 0 or len(self.expnameLine.text()) ==       
0 or len(self.expnumbLine.text()) == 0 or len(self.filenameLine.text()) ==    
0 or
len(self.savenameLine.text()) == 0 or len(self.delayLine.text()) == 0 or  
len(self.timeLine.text()) == 0):
        reply = QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Message', u'Заполните пустые 
поля!!!')
        reply

    else:
        self.myname = self.nameLine.text()
        self.expname = self.expnameLine.text()
        self.expnumb = self.expnumbLine.text()
        self.filename = self.filenameLine.text()
        self.savename = self.savenameLine.text()
        self.ex_event = True
        self.close()   


def keyPressEvent(self, e):

    if e.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
        self.close()

    elif e.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
        self.saving()
```

В классе Device прописан ряд функций, которые будут работать с данными, введёнными пользователем в форме. Например:

```
class Device(object):


def __init__(self):


    self.rm = visa.ResourceManager()
    self.instr = None

    super(Device, self).__init__()


def function1(self):
    code

def function2(self):
    code

def function3(self)
    code
```

Эта библиотека будет в дальнейшем использована для написания скриптов. Вот пробный скрипт:

```
import sys
import DevMeasMod as dmm
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


app = QCoreApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
data = dmm.DataInput()
app.exec_()

in = data.Device()
in.function3()
in.function1()
in.function2()
```

Если в классе DataInput в методе saving прописать self.close(), то по нажатию кнопки "Запуск" форма закрывается и выполняется дальнейший код в виде функций, на этом этапе всё нормально. Однако сейчас появилась задача, заключающаяся в выводе сообщений о состоянии выполнения скрипта и результатов функций в окне, например, в QTextBrowser. При этом код вне окна, то есть идущий после app.exec(), не выполняется без его закрытия, а если прописать этот код до app.exec(), то виснут виджеты окна. Вопрос: можно ли сделать так, чтобы по нажатию кнопки окно не закрывалось, но при этом выполнялся дальнейший код из функций класса Device чтобы выводить результат этих функций в окне? 
Заранее спасибо за Ваше время.

Answer (score 0):

Вы сократии исходный код так, что он не запускается.
   Убрав то, что необходимо, оставив то, что не имеет значения.

Насчет обработки потоков вы поторопились, они пока у вас не наблюдаются.

К библиотеке DevMeasMod не прикасаемся, оперируем только классами, которые здесь используются.

Обратите внимание `self.setLayout` должен быть один.
   Вы как-то странно проверяете заполняемость полей `QLineEdit`. Если в каких-то из этих полей должны быть числа, то лучше использовать виджет `QSpinBox`.

Вопросы в комментариях не задавайте. Попробуйте все осмыслить. Если будут вопросы, пишите новый вопрос, прикрепляйте пример, который запускается и понятно описывайте проблему. Удачи вам.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

# В классе Device прописан ряд функций, которые будут работать с данными, 
# введёнными пользователем в форме.
class Device(QWidget):   # (object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Device, self).__init__()
#        self.rm    = visa.ResourceManager()      # ???
        self.instr = None                         # ???

        self.textBrowser = QTextBrowser()
        layoutV = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layoutV.addWidget(self.textBrowser)

    def function1(self):
        print("def function 1(self):")
        self.textBrowser.append("def function 1(self): ...")

    def function2(self):
        print("def function 2(self):")
        self.textBrowser.append("def function 22 (self): ...")

    def function3(self):  # :
        print("def function 3(self):")
        self.textBrowser.append("def function 333 (self): ...")


# В классе DataInput создаётся окно для ввода пользователем данных. 
class DataInput(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DataInput, self).__init__()

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.expnameLabel = QLabel("expnameLabel")
        self.expnameLine  = QLineEdit("expnameLine")
        self.expnumbLabel = QLabel("expnumbLabel")
        self.expnumbLine  = QLineEdit("expnumbLine")
        self.filenameLabel= QLabel("filenameLabel")
        self.filenameLine = QLineEdit("filenameLine")
        self.savenameLabel= QLabel("savenameLabel")
        self.savenameLine = QLineEdit("savenameLine")
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.ex_event = False

        oImage  = QImage('D:/_Qt/img/pyqt.jpg')
        sImage  = oImage.scaled(QSize(600, 455))
        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Window, QBrush(sImage))
        self.setPalette(palette)

        self.header1 = QLabel(self)
        self.header1.setText('Информация об эксперименте: ')
        self.header1.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 14, 70))

        self.header2 = QLabel(self)
        self.header2.setText('Параметры процесса: ')
        self.header2.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 14, 70))

        self.empty = QLabel(self)
        self.empty.setText('empty')                        # ???

        self.nameLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.nameLabel.setText(u'Эксперимент проводит: ')
        self.nameLabel.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 12, 60))
        self.nameLine = QLineEdit(self)

        openFile = QAction(QIcon('Ok.png'), 'Open', self)  # ???
        openFile.setStatusTip('Open file')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)

        chbtn = QPushButton(self)
        chbtn.setIcon(QIcon('Ok.png'))
        chbtn.setIconSize(QSize(20, 15))
        chbtn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

        chbtns = QPushButton(self)
        chbtns.setIcon(QIcon('Ok.png'))
        chbtns.setIconSize(QSize(20, 15))
        chbtns.clicked.connect(self.saveDialog)

        btn = QPushButton(u'Запуск', self)
        btn.setAutoDefault(True)
        btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: #7fc7ff")
        btn.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 12, 65))
        btn.clicked.connect(self.saving) 

        mainwindow = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainwindow)

        vertical1 = QHBoxLayout()
        vertical1.addWidget(self.header1)
        vertical1.addWidget(self.header2)           # + ???
        vertical1.addWidget(self.empty)             # + ???

#        self.setLayout(vertical1)

        grid1 = QGridLayout()
        grid1.addWidget(self.nameLabel, 1, 0)
        grid1.addWidget(self.nameLine, 1, 1)

#        grid1.addWidget(QLabel("expnameLabel"), 2, 0)        
        grid1.addWidget(self.expnameLabel, 2, 0)
        grid1.addWidget(self.expnameLine, 2, 1)
        grid1.addWidget(self.expnumbLabel, 3, 0)
        grid1.addWidget(self.expnumbLine, 3, 1)
        grid1.addWidget(self.filenameLabel, 4, 0)
        grid1.addWidget(self.filenameLine, 4, 1)
        grid1.addWidget(self.savenameLabel, 5, 0)
        grid1.addWidget(self.savenameLine, 5, 1)
        grid1.addWidget(chbtn, 4, 2)
        grid1.addWidget(chbtns, 5, 2)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(btn)
        hbox.addStretch(1)

        mainwindow.addLayout(vertical1) 
        mainwindow.addLayout(grid1)
        mainwindow.addStretch(1)
        mainwindow.addLayout(hbox)

#        self.setLayout(hbox)
#        self.setLayout(grid1)

        self.center()


    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def showDialog(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 
                               'Open file', 
                               '/home/gamma-dna/.config/spyder')[0]
        self.filenameLine.setText(fname)

    def saveDialog(self):
        put = os.getcwd()
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Save file', put)[0]
        self.savenameLine.setText(fname)

    def saving(self):
#        if (len(self.nameLine.text())     or        # == 0   ???
        if (not self.nameLine.text()     or        # == 0   ???
            not self.expnameLine.text()  or        # == 0   ???
            not self.expnumbLine.text()  or        # == 0   ??? 
            not self.filenameLine.text() or        # == 0   ??? 
            not self.savenameLine.text() #or        # == 0   ??? 
#            not self.delayLine.text()    or        # delayLine ??? == 0   ???  
#            not self.timeLine.text()             # timeLine ???
            ):

            reply = QMessageBox.critical(self, 
                                        'Message', 
                                        u'Заполните пустые поля!!!')
# ???            reply

        else:
            self.myname   = self.nameLine.text()
            self.expname  = self.expnameLine.text()
            self.expnumb  = self.expnumbLine.text()
            self.filename = self.filenameLine.text()
            self.savename = self.savenameLine.text()
            self.ex_event = True

#            self.close()   

            self.device = Device()
            self.device.show()
            self.device.function1()
            self.device.function2()
            self.device.function3()


    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()
        elif e.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
            self.saving()  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

#    import DevMeasMod as dmm        
#    data = dmm.DataInput()
    data = DataInput()
    data.setWindowTitle(u'Ввод данных')
    data.setFixedSize(600, 455)
    data.setToolTip('Пожалуйста введите информацию о проводимом эксперименте')
#    self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    data.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
# то что ниже никогда не выполнится
    inDevice = data.Device()  # in ??? плохое имя !!!
    inDevice.function3()
    inDevice.function1()
    inDevice.function2()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]